# Image doesn't show up on JButton unless I click on the button

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

Im trying to draw an image to my JButtons using the following code. When I run the program, the buttons are blank unless if I click on them (then the image shows up while the mouse is pressed).

```
private void addBtnImages() {
    JButton rectangle;
    //Rectangle
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(25, 25, 2);
    Graphics2D gc = img.createGraphics();
    gc.drawRect(5, 5, 15, 15);
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(img);
    rectangle = new JButton(ic);
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: You have not provided enough code as well as explanation for us to diagnose the cause and help you with a solution. Consider providing more code as well as a screenshot of the issue if possible.

Comment: You create a button but don't add it to the frame so I don't know how you could possibly click on it. So  this code is not related to your problem

Comment: Check the answers. The Button does get added to the frame, just not here.

Comment: @Koverman47,  The code you posted is completely unrelated to your question, so why did you post the code?  All the variables, button, image are local so this method does nothing. When you post code you post code that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Actually it is perfectly relevant. When you draw with Graphics2D (see code above) onto a BufferedImage (see code above) the color defaults to the same as the JButton which is why you have to set the color to something else (see code below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. The color of the image defaulted to the same color as the JButton background. All I did was add the following line after I declared gc:

```
gc.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Now when I run the code, the image shows up black instead of defaulting to the same color as the button which allowed it to blend in.